# add_dependencies(listener beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp) explanation

Tags: ros-melodic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently doing the ROS tutorial on **Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)**. I do not understand the explanation for including this line `add_dependencies(talker beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)` in the package `CMakeLists.txt` file. Here is the accompanying explanation of the line:

> Note that you have to add dependencies for the executable targets to message generation targets:
>
> `add_dependencies(talker beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)`
>
> This makes sure message headers of
> this package are generated before
> being used. If you use messages from
> other packages inside your catkin
> workspace, you need to add
> dependencies to their respective
> generation targets as well, because
> catkin builds all projects in
> parallel.

What is headers of the package used by? What is `beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp`? Is it the message generation target? What is a message generation target?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328490/add_dependencies(listener-beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)-explanation/) by [Ananda](https://answers.ros.org/users/44055/ananda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-07-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can read [this](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt) for more information about CMakeLists (section 8).
Here is a related [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/254968/difference-between-_generate_messages_cpp-and-_exported_targets/) about the differtence between "_generate_messages_cpp" and "_exported_targets". [This](https://answers.ros.org/question/60994/pkg_name_generate_messages_cpp-vs-pkg_name_gencpp/) one gives also some info on _generate_messages_cpp.

The difference of catkin and project exported targets (not only messages) is well explained in [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/286311/when-is-catkin_exported_targets-needed/) answer.

Basically, `beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp` means that the messages should be build before the target since the target is using them. If you have a package which builds messages and executable that use them, then you need to create an explicit dependency on the automatically generated message target so that they are built in the correct order.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2019-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1